# Pasar Array PHP a Javascript - json_encode ( Error )

Tags: php, javascript, json, jsonarray

Quisiera pedir de vuestra ayuda, he pasado semanas tratando de encontrar el problema al tratar de pasar un array en php a javascript mediante json_encode. Esto para un proyecto de geolocalización de casos COVID para mi trabajo.
En el localhost con xampp funciona excelente puedo pasar el array y funciona todo sin ningún problema. El tema que al subirlo al servidor me arroja error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'` esto al momento de ejecutar `variablejs = <?php echo $variablejson;?>;` al revisar la depuración por consola me sale esto: `variablejs = ;`  es decir no toma el código php y lo deja en blanco.

Por favor si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradecería enormemente.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
   integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     
<script
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
<?php
    // Datos de la base de datos
    $usuario = "root";
    $password = "";
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $basededatos = "bd_cv19das";
        
    // creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
    $conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $password ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
    
    // Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
    $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );

    // establecer y realizar consulta. guardamos en variable.
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM sptm";
    $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
    
    // Motrar el resultado de los registro de la base de datos
    // Encabezado de la tabla
    echo "<table borde='2'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Nombre</th>";
    echo "<th>Fecha</th>";
    echo "<th>Longitud</th>";
    echo "<th>Latitud</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    
    $arreglo=array();
    $variablejson=array();
    // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
    while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
    {
    
    $rows[] = $columna; 
    $arreglo[] = $columna;
    $longitude[] = $columna['longitude'];
    $latitude[] = $columna['latitude'];
    $name[] = $columna['name'];
    $date[] = $columna['date'];
    
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $columna['name'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['date'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['longitude'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['latitude'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>"; // Fin de la tabla
    $variablejson=json_encode($arreglo,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
    // cerrar conexión de base de datos
    mysqli_close( $conexion );
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  

variablejs = <?php echo $variablejson;?>;
console.log(variablejs) ;

//jsVar = variablejs;   
//var stringified = JSON.stringify(jsVar);
//var addressPoints = JSON.parse(stringified);
//console.log(addressPoints)    
//var arreglo = <?php //echo json_encode($variablejson); ?>;
//console.log(arreglo)

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Acá código ejecutado en en Localhost funcionando sin problemas.

[image: Array en Localhost]

[image: Array en Servidor]

La consulta SQL se ejecuta todo bien, puedo acceder a la BD, de hecho la tabla la obtengo sin problemas con toda la información, pero al pasar de php a javascript en el servidor no funciona. Pero para poder obtener la geolocalización en el Mapa la necesito en Javascript.

Ojala alguien pueda ayudarme.

[image: Como pueden ver, la consulta se ejecuta sin problema, no hay error en conexión con la BD ni nada.]

Comment: No debes mezclar PHP con JS. Usa una llamada Ajax y seguro todo irá mejor. Saludos

Comment: Es probable que [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) este devolviendo `false`. De ser así el problema esta relacionado con la codificación de los datos en la variable `$arreglo`.

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras Alguna ayuda de como poder pasar el Dato con Ajax, lo que pasa que despues estos datos los paso a Leaflet y  los geolocalizo en el mapa con javascript, por eso pase de PHP a javascript la variable.

Comment: @Marcos tiene razon, el problema esta en el json encode, si tu rutina depende de esto, asegurate de que el resultado esta bien formateado y no genera error

Comment: @JhonSilver pero como se puede explicar que en localhost, pase todo sin problemas y solo al cargar en el servidor arroja error. Probé actualizando versión de PHP, cargue en otro hosting para probar y lo mismo. Alguna ayuda de como pasar un array de php a javascript pero que no sea con json, con Ajax se podrá?

Answer (score 0):

Después de cientos de prueba y error, di con la solución:

Dentro del While agregue la siguiente linea:

```js
$arreglo[] = array('longitude'=> $longitude, 'latitude'=> $latitude, 'name'=> $name, 'date'=> $date);
```

y despues puede usarse sin problemas el json_encode

```js
variablejs=(<?php echo json_encode($arreglo) ?>);
console.log(variablejs);
```